# On Mouse Over change the RotatorType property of RadRotator using javaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**Below is my Code:- But its not working **

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="TestRotator" runat="server" Width="560px" Height="140px"
  ScrollDuration="2000" FrameDuration="20000" ItemHeight="120" ItemWidth="520"
  WrapFrames="true" Skin="Forest" SlideShowAnimation-Type="none" RotatorType="SlideShowButtons" onClientMouseover="Rotater()">
```

**javaScript:-**

```
function Rotator() {

    var RadRotator = document.getElementById('<%= TestRotator.ClientId %>');
    if (RadRotator.OnClientMouseOver = true){

       RadRotator.style.RotatorType = "SlideShowButtons";

    }
    else if (RadRotator.OnClientMouseOut = false)
    {

        RadRotator.RotatorType="SlideShow";

    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually explain what "not working" means, e.g., does the code run with unexpected behaviour, or not run at all, but there are some obvious problems:

The way you spell the function name is not consistent:

```
onClientMouseover="Rotater()"
// compared with
function Rotator() {
```

Also, I'm not sure if case matters, but maybe you should have:

```
OnClientMouseOver="Rotator()"
```

And then within your function your two if statements are using the `=` assignment operator instead of the `==` or `===` comparison operators.

Also, within one if statement you set `RadRotator.style.RotatorType`, but in the other if statement you set `RadRotator.RotatorType` - I don't know if `.style.` is correct, but I assume they should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am trying using both but none of it is working  RadRotator.style.RotatorType =SlideShowButtons";RadRotator.RotatorType

Comment: my flow is going till this line  RadRotator.style.RotatorType = "SlideShowButtons"; and at this line it is giving error "Object doesn't Support this property and method."